# Constraint Validator validates Entity before Entity is ready in Symfony 2

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

My Symfony2 (2.4.2) application has a form, and an entity which I have set some validation constraints on some fields. One of the entity's variables is an array which should not be blank.

The form has a field which is not mapped to the entity directly. The input is a comma-delimited string; this string will be `preg_split` into an array and saved to the instance variable aforementioned. This operation is triggered by `FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT`.

However, when I submit the form, even though the input string is not empty, the form shows that the validation fails. I did a bit of debugging and found that the validation actually happens before `FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT`. I have tried other `FormEvents` but no luck.

Is there a way to trigger the event before the validation?

Note: The scenario above is shortened, it'd be too long for me to ask a question if the context is my real application.

Comment: why don't you do this in `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT`?

Comment: Why is the form field not mapped to the entity? Is it a validation error because the field is empty at the time or because it isn't an array looking like after POST_SUBMIT? Since it's not empty maybe you should change the format of validation to look like before the splitting event.

Comment: Use DataTransformers for this sort of operation.  Not form events.

Comment: @JamesHalsall As I've said, I've tried all FormEvents but no luck.

Comment: @SenseException Because the client requires the input field be a text field and allow users to enter some phone numbers in the format '000000, 000000, 000000...'.

Comment: You can validate that input format or use @Cerad's solution. I would prefer the DataTransformer too.

Comment: @Cerad Could you please post an answer so that I can mark your solution as correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DataTransformers for this sort of operation. Not form events.

The data transformer will kick in before the validation.  The transformer will transform whatever the user types into whatever you expect internally.  The validation will then operate on the internal data format.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html